# bad view when refreshing

Tags: css, jquery-slider

There is a problem.When im refreshing page,slide seems really bad for a while(till all files load) about 500-700ms.

im using rocketslider for jquery.

  ***server side*** -> nginx server,varnish(cache mechanism) wordpress

    ***cdn:*** cloudflare (auto minify activated for css,js)

when click f5 button on site,(in ~500ms i think)
[image: when refreshing]

and after ~600-700ms maybe lower or more its only example but its lower than 1sec.
[image]

im using dark style theme,so it looks very bad.how to prevent it?
i never want to see scroll bars.. any idea?

my style.css for slide..

```
  filmslayt {width:976px;float:left;height:auto;padding:0px;margin:1px;border:1px solid #191919;margin-bottom:10px;}

    .filmslaytc {width:974px;float:left;height:auto;padding:0px;border:1px solid #333333;background:#191919;}

    #myslides{background:#121212;}

    .stepcarousel{position: relative;overflow: scroll;width: 940px;height: 150px;margin: 0px 14px 0px 14px;}

    .stepcarousel .belt{position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;margin-left:3px;}

    .stepcarousel .panel{float: left;margin: 4px 16px;width:114px;background:#14181a;height:140px;border:1px solid #333333;transition: all .3s linear;-o-transition: all .3s linear;-moz-transition: all .3s linear;-webkit-transition: all .3s linear;}

    .stepcarousel .panel img{background:#040404;margin: 1px 1px 1px 2px;padding:0px 0px;}   

    .stepcarousel .panel:hover {background:#4679aa;border:1px solid #4679aa;transition: all .3s linear;-o-transition: all .3s linear;-moz-transition: all .3s linear;-webkit-transition: all .3s linear;}
```

real example [site](http://www.fullhdfilmsizle.com)

Comment: Images are cached and so this has nothing to do with the server. have a retina display? ur display size? u may save a whole copy of the page and try it as simple local html to redesign the test

Comment: i saved page as html to my local and tried.no problem when i try refresh to page,no scrollbars.but in server,when click f5,you see scroll bars for a while(maybe 500ms-till load all files).its really bad.my pc full hd.dont understand what u mean retina display.you can check site.i added to my post.click refresh and you will see scroll bars for a while.

Comment: give `height=150px` to `filmslayt` & `filmslaytc`

Comment: i tried to give fixed values to heights but still same

Comment: Also add it to `.belt`

Comment: i added it too.but still same.but ithink itsnot about fixed values.coz its not only y axis(mean right scroll bar). there are right and bottom scroll bars.but all width values fixed.i hope i told you properly.

Comment: i tried more bigger fixed values than panel.but scroll bars still here..